# How to know when a function will throw and when to use noexcept

Tags: c++, exception

When declaring a function, you are able to use the `noexcept` specifier to declare that the function will not throw:

```
int foo() noexcept
{
  return 10;
}
```

However, how does one determine when a function will throw? I know that use of the `new` operator can potentially throw `std::bad_alloc`, but what are some other expressions/operators that can throw? Is there a way to explicitly determine if it will?

Comment: Anything you use in your function should have a exception specification.  If you use anything that potentially throws then your function could potentially throw, unless you handle it in the function.

Comment: For someone else's function - read the documentation. For your own function, if you don't throw anything (or call a function that could), nothing gets thrown.

Comment: Surprisingly, `noexcept` specifier does not declare that function will not throw. It declares that thrown exceptions will not propagate from it and instead  `terminate` will be invoked.

Comment: Some static code analyser spot methods which can be `noexcept` (functions which only call `noexcept` functions and which don't throw by themselves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but what are some other expressions/operators that can throw?

Potentially-throwing expressions are defined as (according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec))

> An expression e is potentially-throwing if:
>
> - e is a function call to a potentially-throwing function or pointer to function
> - e makes an implicit call to a potentially-throwing function (such as an overloaded operator, an allocation function in a new-expression, a constructor for a function argument, or a destructor if e is a full-expression)
> - e is a throw-expression
> - e is a dynamic_cast that casts a polymorphic reference type
> - e is a typeid expression applied to a dereferenced pointer to a polymorphic type
> - e has an immediate subexpression that is potentially-throwing

Also, any expression that has undefined behaviour.

A function that is not declared `noexcept` is *potentially-throwing* as far as the language is concerned, even if it might never throw.

> Is there a way to explicitly determine if it will?

In general no, you cannot determine whether an expression *will* throw - at least not in polynomial time assuming P ≠ NP.

However, you *can* determine whether an expression is potentially-throwing using the `noexcept`-expression:

```
void foo() noexcept;
void bar() {
    // nothing that might throw
}

std::cout << noexcept(1+1);                        // prints 1
std::cout << noexcept(foo())                       // prints 1
std::cout << noexcept(bar())                       // prints 0
std::cout << noexcept(new char);                   // prints 0
std::cout << noexcept(throw 1);                    // prints 0
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to determine for every function whether it will throw an exception or not (this is at least hard as [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). However, there are some cases where you **can** know **for sure** that the function **will not** throw an exception.
One of them is your trivial example of a constant function returning 10.

Comment: Nah, it is not possible only because of the ugly language rules. If could have been a trivial matter if standard committee decided to enforce exception specifiers and make them a part of function signature instead of removing them.

Comment: Not sure you can create a program (which is not ill formed) where `noexcept` of function cannot be deduced.

Comment: @VTT Enforce ES how?